# Как при делении двух целых чисел типа int получить вещественное число?

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет.

```
int a = 22;
int b = 7;

var result = a / b;

Console.WriteLine( "{0} / {1} = {2}", a, b, result );
```

Результат равен 3, а мне-то нужно 3,142857143. Как это реализовать?

Comment: очень баянистый вопрос. Просто приведите один из операндов к double: 

    int a = 22;
    int b = 7;

    double result = (double)a / b;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
       var result = (double) a / b;
```

Comment: @Zufir спасибо тебе. Хотелось бы еще для красоты немного округлить результат. Например, 3,143 можно сделать так?

Comment: Math.Round() с нужной точностью

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, привести хотя бы одно из них к типу float:

```
var result = (float) a / b;
```

В арифметических операциях все операнды приводятся к наиболее точному типу: `short -> int -> long -> float -> double`.

Comment: @fori1ton и тебе спасибо. -)